# Why, in C++, is my class constructor described by Visual Studio as having "2+ Overloads"?

Tags: c++, class, oop, constructor

I have a TreeNode class with a constructor that sets the value of the node, and sets the left and right pointers to null.

```
class TreeNode {
 public:
  int val = 0;
  TreeNode *left;
  TreeNode *right;

  TreeNode(int x) {
    this->val = x;
    left = right = nullptr;
  }
};
```

When I hover my mouse over `TreeNode(int x)` I get a message that states:

```
TreeNode::TreeNode(int x)

+2 overloads
```

What does 'overloads' mean in this context? From what I understand, overloading would occur if I, for example, had an additional function within the `TreeNode` class also named `TreeNode()`.

Thanks for any explanation!

Comment: I would say auto-generated copy/move constructors.

Comment: The other overloads might be the one, the compiler will add implicitly, e.g. the copy constructor `TreeNode::TreeNode(const TreeNode&)`.

Comment: As the same way you do `int val = 0;`, you might do `TreeNode *left = nullptr;`

Comment: You can do this explicitly: `TreeNode(const TreeNode&) = default;` or tell the compiler to not to define it implicitly by `TreeNode(const TreeNode&) = delete;` (which I would prefer due to the child pointers which may express ownership).

Comment: And prefer initialization over assignment `explicit TreeNode(int x) : value(x) {}`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your class `TreeNode` has implicit auto-generated copy/move constructors.

Those should be the overload pointed by intellisense.

Comment: Funny: If I add `TreeNode(const TreeNode&) = delete;` to the OP's code, the hover gives me the expected *+1 overload*. However, if I then add `TreeNode(TreeNode&&) = delete;` (deleting also the move c'tor) then it goes back to *+2 overloads*.

Comment: @AdrianMole Don't trust IntelliSense... ;-)